# Magento model not fetching data

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, sales-quote

I am using magento 1.9.

I want to retrieve data from `sales_flat_quote_address` table in onepagecheckout, after saved the `shipping method`. I have used the following codes. But no result.

Code 1:

> $quote_address = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address')->getCollection();
>
> $quote_address->addFieldToFilter("address_type", array("eq" =>
>   "shipping"));
>
> $quote_address->addFieldToFilter("quote_id", array("eq" =>
>   $quote_c->getId()));

Code 2:

> $resource  = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
>
> $connRead  = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
>
> $sqlCdnImageName = "SELECT shipping_method FROM
>   `sales_flat_quote_address` WHERE  `address_type` = 'shipping'  AND
>   `quote_id` = " .$quote_c->getId() . ";";
>
> $results = $connRead->fetchAll($sqlCdnImageName);

Code 2 generates this query:

> SELECT shipping_method FROM `sales_flat_quote_address` WHERE  `address_type` = 'shipping'  AND `quote_id` = 123

But the data is not coming.
please help to solve this.

**Update:** This quote data comes out when user doing checkout by logged in. But the data returns empty when guest checkout at the first time. After refresh the page(i mean 2nd time) the data comes out.

I found the **updated time changes** in the data printed and the data comes in the phpMyAdmin by executing the query. Is this affect the result in any way?

Data comes from the Model and query in the Phtml file:

> [created_at] => 2017-03-09 09:50:06
>
> [updated_at] => **2017-03-09 09:51:04**

Data from PhpMyAdmin SqlQuery:

> [created_at] => 2017-03-09 09:50:06
>
> [updated_at] => **2017-03-09 09:51:51**

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you use method2 b'cuz method 1 is right

```
$quote_address = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address')->getCollection();

$quote_address->addFieldToFilter("address_type", array("eq" => "shipping"));

$quote_address->addFieldToFilter("quote_id", array("eq" => $quote_c->getId()));

print_r($quote_address->getData());//for printing data

foreach($quote_address as $address){
   print_r($address);   
}
```

Comment: I have tried this already. But no result. This quote data comes out when user doing checkout by logged in. But the data returns empty when guest checkout at the first time. After refresh the page(i mean 2nd time) the data comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$sqlCdnImageName = "SELECT shipping_method FROM ". $resource->getTableName('sales/quote_address') . " WHERE address_type = 'shipping' AND  quote_id = $quote_c->getId()";
```

The reason for not getting data could be that you have used `table_prefix` in for your magento tables while setup.
`$resource->getTableName('sales/quote_address')` will give you exact table name with table prefix values if any.

Comment: I have tried this already. But no result. This quote data comes out when user doing checkout by logged in. But the data returns empty when guest checkout at the first time. After refresh the page(i mean 2nd time) the data comes out.

Comment: You should add full details to your question. So it does not confuse others. Please update your question with your full requirements.

Comment: Updated the question